# Trying to get SUM - Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting the error when trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(MAX(mileage_end) - MIN(mileage_begin)) AS [BusinessMiles]
FROM Expense_Mileage
WHERE username = 'x' AND period = 'January - 2021'
GROUP BY mileage_date
```

Would like a single sum for the period as a result

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . Do you want a separate row for each date?

```
SELECT mileage_date, MAX(mileage_end) - MIN(mileage_begin) AS [BusinessMiles]
FROM Expense_Mileage
WHERE username = 'x' AND period = 'January - 2021'
GROUP BY mileage_date
```

Or do you want one row, which might be:

```
SELECT MAX(mileage_end) - MIN(mileage_begin) AS [BusinessMiles]
FROM Expense_Mileage
WHERE username = 'x' AND period = 'January - 2021';
```

Or use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(BusinessMiles)
FROM (SELECT mileage_date, MAX(mileage_end) - MIN(mileage_begin) AS BusinessMiles
      FROM Expense_Mileage
      WHERE username = 'x' AND period = 'January - 2021'
      GROUP BY mileage_date
     ) em
```

Comment: THANK YOU, the last one was the desired result